# How do I cycle through images in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I want to have the button's image cycle through all possible pizza images, but instead it throws the following error when I click on it:

```
self.config(image=next(self.images))
AttributeError: 'buttonInitialize' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Here's the code. I know it's ugly, sorry. I barely understand python classes, so I couldn't figure out how to factor the repetitive parts out

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

class buttonInitialize:

    def __init__ (self,enabler):
        frame=Frame(enabler)
        frame.pack()

        pizzaList=[]
        pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="Cheese.png").zoom(10))
        pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="AvocadoWSauce.png").zoom(10))
        pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="AvocadoWCheese.png").zoom(10))

        self.images=cycle(pizzaList)
        self.printButton=Button(frame,image=pizzaList[0] ,command=self.nextPizza)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def nextPizza(self):
        self.config(image=next(self.images))

root=Tk()
c=buttonInitialize(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think `buttonInitialize` has a `config` method?

Comment: Can I give it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of self.config(), use self.printButton.config()